# Download a file without file ending nodejs

Tags: node.js, image, download

For example: `https://preview.redd.it/04o5k2n06zd71.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=7baa25e7e1bde3436cb2a265e2fc8c6cb9a758ee`

how can I download / load that image to a buffer

Note:
The ending can always be different.

Comment: What does "without file ending nodejs" mean?

Comment: In nodejs, any of the http request libraries [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/3143) are good for making an http request and getting the response.  My personal favorite is `got()`, but all in that list are good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an implementation using the `got()` library for nodejs:

```
const got = require('got');

const url =
    'https://preview.redd.it/04o5k2n06zd71.jpg?width=960&crop=smart&auto=webp&s=7baa25e7e1bde3436cb2a265e2fc8c6cb9a758ee';

got(url, { responseType: 'buffer' }).then(result => {
    // result.body contains a Buffer object with the image in it
    console.log(`content-type: ${result.headers['content-type']}`);
    console.log(`isBuffer: ${Buffer.isBuffer(result.body)}`);
    console.log(result.body);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

You can run this code directly with nodejs (after installing the `got()` library).  When I run it, it generates this output:

```
content-type: image/jpeg
isBuffer: true
<Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff e2 02 1c 49 43 43 5f 50 52 4f 46 49 4c 45 00 01 01 00 00 02 0c 6c 63 6d 73 02 10 00 00 ... 89335 more bytes>
```